# VB.NEt - Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net

Im having an error message saying "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

```
    Dim Conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="  
    Dim dataFile = "E:\TME Review\TME Review Database.accdb"
    Conn.ConnectionString = provider & dataFile 
    Conn.Open()  
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Monthly where [Date Ended]= '" + TextBox3.Text + "'", Conn)  
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

[Date Ended] data type is text and the content of textbox3 is a string value. I double checked. Any idea why am i getting error data type mismatch? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to change + to &.

Comment: Your passing the date wrong...

Comment: i'm passing the date wrong? can you pelase explain it ?

Comment: Wrap your dates in `#` and use `-` instead of the slashes.

Comment: If it's a date type use date type not a string!

Comment: Does is work if you hardcode `SELECT * FROM Monthly where [Date Ended]= 'Aug/2016'` ?

Comment: If `Date Ended` is a text column (and therefore not a date at all) then the code shown, though very flawed, should work.  I suspect that the column is not actually a text column based on what is shown.

Answer (score -1):

In VB, to concatenate strings you must utilize "&" instead "+".

**EDIT**

That is the right answer IF all data is string...
But, if your DATE is set like '12/05/2009' you must put it enclosed #, like:

```
  where [End Date] = '#12/05/2009#'
```

Comment: That isn't the solution and that's not the correct error for that.

Comment: but im not trying to concatenate strings ,im searching data within the database with the date selected/inputed .

Comment: Marceline, are you sure your database field is in string format?

Comment: yup , i can take a screenshot if you want .

Answer (score -1):

Check the value inputted in your textbox. In this case where you're filtering out records using a date field, you better check first the value in your textbox whether it's a valid date or not before using it for your OleDBCommand.

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand= Nothing
If IsDate(TextBox3.Text)= True Then
    cmd= New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Monthly where [Date Ended]= '" + TextBox3.Text + "'", Conn)
End If
```

Comment: the value inputted in the textbox is a string value , which is typed manually (ex. Aug/2016)

Comment: Aug/2016 is not a valid date. I suggest for you to use datetimepicker for this if possible.